# TextToSpeech in Android RecyclerView: Error: android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, text-to-speech, android-viewholder

I have implemented TextToSpeech in a RecyclerView. Each card item has a button to initialize speaking. I have set OnClickListener to button in MyViewHolder. MyViewHolder implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener. The app is working fine.

However, I must **shut down and stop the TextToSpeech** when activity is finished. Since I can't override onDestroy() method in MyViewHolder class, How can I do it?

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

private Button btnSpeak;
private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;

public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(itemView.getContext(), this);
        btnSpeak= (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textToSpeech.speak(wordToSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        });
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }
    }
}
```

The log is showing following error for every card item:

```
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech that was originally bound here.
```

Comment: when you call  'textToSpeech.stop();' and 'textToSpeech.shutdown();'

Comment: That's the problem I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Make your Parent Activity or Fragment implement the `onClick` listener and Text to Speech. Handle the Text to Speech login globally there.

Comment: I've tried it. When the user clicks TextToSpeech button, it should speak the content that particular card has. Each CardView has different content.

Comment: you need to call that when your activity is destroyed, moreover you can use it as per your architecture of the application.

Comment: @brandall I am implementing your suggestion. I may have missed something.